# how to change shape and colors when clicking menuitems in java

Tags: java, swing, colors, awt, paintcomponent

Im having trouble changing the colors of a certain shape. But when user click on a menuitem, it will successfully change into another shape. Now the problem is I cannot think of a solution that will solve this one. Can anyone help me on this? Help are much appreciated. Thank you.

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics shapes)
    {
        super.paintComponent(shapes);
        switch(colorNo)
        {
            case 0 : color = Color.RED;break;
            case 1 : color = Color.BLUE;break;
            case 2 : color = Color.MAGENTA;break;
        }
        switch(numbers)
        {
            case 0 : circle(shapes);break;
            case 1 : rectangle(shapes);break;
            case 2 : square(shapes);break;
            case 3 : triangle(shapes);break;
        }  
    }

    public void circle(Graphics shapes)
    {
        shapes.setColor(color);
        shapes.fillOval(250,100, 100, 100);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
        if(click.getSource() == circle){
            numbers = 0;
            repaint();
        }else if(click.getSource() == square){
            numbers = 1; repaint();
        }else if(click.getSource() == rectangle){
            numbers = 2; repaint();
        }else if(click.getSource() == triangle){
            numbers = 3; repaint();
        }
        if(click.getSource() == red){
            colorNo = 0; repaint();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple -- in your paintComponent method, **after** your super's paintComponent call, and **before** your switch statement where you set the shape, set the Graphics object's Color, in the same way that you set the shape. You'll of course have to add a listener to each of your color menu items for this to work.

It's **much** easier and cleaner if you use AbstractActions instead of having everything share the same ActionListener. For example, this code doesn't do exactly what you're trying to do, but it can give you some ideas.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;


public class MyShapes extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private Color color = Color.WHITE;

    public MyShapes() {
        JMenu colorMenu = new JMenu("Color");
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("Black", Color.BLACK)));
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("White", Color.WHITE)));
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("Red", Color.RED)));
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("Blue", Color.BLUE)));
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("Green", Color.GREEN)));
        menuBar.add(colorMenu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }

    private class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Color actionColor;

        public ColorAction(String name, Color color) {
            super(name);
            this.actionColor = color;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            color = actionColor;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyShapes mainPanel = new MyShapes();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyShapes");
        frame.setJMenuBar(mainPanel.getMenuBar());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that you could draw your shapes in the same way -- by filling a variable from within the menu item's action's actionPerformed method. Only this time the variable that is of the DrawShape interface type and will use it for its **method**, here the `public void draw(Graphics g)`. This type of program design pattern is called the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyShapes extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private Color color = null;
    public DrawShape drawShape = null;

    public MyShapes() {
        // create and fill colorMenu
        JMenu colorMenu = new JMenu("Color");
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("Black", Color.BLACK)));
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("White", Color.WHITE)));
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("Red", Color.RED)));
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("Blue", Color.BLUE)));
        colorMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ColorAction("Green", Color.GREEN)));

        // create and fill shapeMenu
        JMenu shapeMenu = new JMenu("Shape");
        shapeMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new DrawShapeAction("Square", new DrawShape() {

            @Override
            public void draw(Graphics g) {
                int x = getWidth() / 4;
                int y = getHeight() / 4;
                int width = getWidth() / 2;
                int height = getHeight() / 2;
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            }
        })));
        shapeMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new DrawShapeAction("Circle", new DrawShape() {

            @Override
            public void draw(Graphics g) {
                int x = getWidth() / 4;
                int y = getHeight() / 4;
                int width = getWidth() / 2;
                int height = getHeight() / 2;
                g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
            }
        })));
        shapeMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new DrawShapeAction("Triangle", new DrawShape() {

            @Override
            public void draw(Graphics g) {
                int[] x = new int[3];
                int[] y = new int[3];
                x[0] = getWidth() / 4;
                x[1] = getWidth() / 2;
                x[2] = 3 * getWidth() / 4;
                y[0] = 3 * getHeight() / 4;
                y[1] = getHeight() / 4;
                y[2] = y[0];
                Polygon polygon = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
                g.fillPolygon(polygon);
            }
        })));

        // add both JMenus to the JMenuBar
        menuBar.add(colorMenu);
        menuBar.add(shapeMenu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // if either color or drawShape are not set, exit this method and draw nothing
        if (color == null || drawShape == null) {
            return;
        }

        // to smooth out the edges
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // set color and call drawShape's draw method
        g.setColor(color);
        drawShape.draw(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }

    private class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Color actionColor;

        public ColorAction(String name, Color color) {
            super(name);
            this.actionColor = color;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MyShapes.this.color = actionColor;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private class DrawShapeAction extends AbstractAction {
        private DrawShape actionDrawShape;

        public DrawShapeAction(String name, DrawShape drawShape) {
            super(name);
            this.actionDrawShape = drawShape;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MyShapes.this.drawShape = actionDrawShape;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private interface DrawShape {
        void draw(Graphics g);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyShapes mainPanel = new MyShapes();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyShapes");
        frame.setJMenuBar(mainPanel.getMenuBar());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be trying to refractor my code after solving the problem. I updated my work but how come it's still not working.. When i click on the red menuitem nothing happen but  clicking the shape menuitem works fine. Can you please check this first?

Comment: @JayGorio: I don't see you adding any listeners to your color menu items.  Where are you doing this? They won't work magically but need to be hooked up do anything.

Comment: $Hovercraft Full Of Eels. My bad didn't notice. Sorry. Okay it's working now.